# Are Core Data generated classes considered my "Model" classes?

Tags: ios, core-data

In Xcode when you create a data model diagram, it will also generate the classes for each entities in the diagram which inherit from NSManagedObject.

The question is are these classes considered my "Model" classes?
OR are they just a bridge between my core data and model classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes these classes generated by xcode are the actual model classes.
I ended up writing my own model classes and then create the data model diagram based on that.
a few notes:

- every class being used by code data
  must inherit from NSManagedObject
- Relationships do not need to be in
  the code, you can just set them in
  the model diagram.
- NSArray and NSMutableArray are not
  accepted, you should use NSSet
  instead
- You should not use int in your model
  you should use NSNumber instead
- If you want the core data models to
  use the classes written by you, then
  you must set the class names in your
  model diagram